# i keep getting: [rospack] Error: stack/package tum_ardrone not found

Tags: ros, stack, package, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am quite new to ROS and ubuntu but whatever i try i am keep getting the error so i hope someone can help me out! I need to install 2 packages:

1. ardrone_autonomy
2. tum_ardrone

i followed these steps for both packages:

**# cd into ros root dir**
roscd

**# clone repository**
git clone git://github.com/tum-vision/tum_ardrone.git tum_ardrone

**# add to ros path (if required)**
export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH:`pwd`/tum_ardrone

**# build package (may take up to 10 minutes)**
rosmake tum_ardrone

even though they are both in opt/ros/hydro i can only run ardrone_autonomy whenever i try to run tum_ardrone i am getting the error.

leroy@leroy-pc:~$ env |grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/hydro/share/ros

ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/hydro/share:/opt/ros/hydro/stacks

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=

ROS_DISTRO=hydro

ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/hydro/etc/ros

and in my .bashrc it says : source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash

i am using ROS hydro and ubuntu 12.04.

thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193288/i-keep-getting:-%5Brospack%5D-error:-stack/package-tum_ardrone-not-found/) by [leroyv13](https://answers.ros.org/users/20275/leroyv13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-09-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the first package should be available via apt-get: `sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-ardrone-autonomy` For the second one, why don't you use the hydro-devel branch of that repo and catkin? Also please don't install anything manually to /opt/ros. Create your own catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Chrissi](https://answers.ros.org/users/15386/chrissi/) with karma: 1642 on 2014-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0